# Convert .match() filter to lowercase Vue JS

Tags: vue.js

I've created a custom search filter in Vue JS. It has more that one filterable field and I'm trying to convert what the user types into an input box to be lowercase to keep it consistent. This is my filter:

```
filteredProperties: function(){
      return this.properties.filter((property) => {
        return property.address.toLowerCase().match(this.searchAddress) && property.type.match(this.searchType) && property.bedrooms.match(this.searchBedrooms) && property.county.match(this.searchCounty)
      });
    }
```

I need to convert `.match(this.searchAddress)` to be lowercase so that it matches up with the main address part.

I've tried:

```
.match(this.searchAddress).toLowerCase()
```

and

```
.match(this.searchAddress.toLowerCase())
```

Comment: what's the problem ?

Comment: It's not working. I'm trying to get my url query for my search, e.g: ?search=HelloWorld to be converted to lowercase through .match(this.searchAddress)

Comment: try to add `.toString()` before each `toLowerCase()`

Comment: That's not working, take a look here: `return property.address.toLowerCase().match(this.searchAddress)` I only need to convert the `searchAddress` to lowercase in the match.

Comment: In my data object I have: `searchAddress: this.$route.query.search` which gets it from the url

Comment: does it return the `this.$route.query.search` correctly?

Comment: Yes, it returns what I want, I just need to convert it to lowercase so that the user can either type lowercase or uppercase and get a result :)

Comment: do you want to compare strings ? and if they are equal you return a boolean?

Comment: Comparing two strings that have been lower-cased should perform the case-insensitive comparison, so I think the problem is elsewhere. Can you provide a fiddle (via [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue)) or link to GitHub repo to reproduce the problem?